# Delete 'this' component onClick instead of using pop

Tags: reactjs

I have a component where I am passing through props to a Delete Button component I have created. Right now with the function, I am simply just using pop and getting rid of the last object in the array. Obviously, this doesn't work well and I want it to be where you click on the delete button for that specific component, and it gets rid of it.

I want to be able to click the Delete button on the individual ticket so that that particular rendered components get deleted. How would you go about doing this?

List of all tickets

```
var Tickets = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function() {
    var i = 0;
    return {
      tickets: [],
    }
  },
  createTicket: function() {
    i++;
    var newTicket = this.state.tickets
    newTicket.push(
      <IndividualTicketInput key={i} deleteTicket={this.deleteTicket} />
    )
    this.setState({newTicket});
    this.forceUpdate();
  },
  deleteTicket: function() {
    var ticket = this.state.tickets
    ticket.pop();
    this.forceUpdate();
  },
  render: function() {
    return (
      <div>
        <IndividualTicketInput/>
        {this.state.tickets}
        <CreateTicket createTicket={this.createTicket} />
      </div>
    );
  }
});
```

Individual ticket component

```
var IndividualTicketInput = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function() {
    return { ticket: {name: '', quantity: '', price: null} };
  },
  nameChange: function(e) {
    var name = this.state.ticket.name;
    this.setState({name: e.target.value })
  },
  quantityChange: function(e) {
    var quantity = this.state.ticket.quantity;
    this.setState({quantity: e.target.value })
  },
  priceChange: function(e) {
    var price = this.state.ticket.price;
    this.setState({price: e.target.value })
  },
  deleteTicket: function(e) {
    this.setState({ ticket: [] });
  },
  render: function() {
    return (
      <ul className="individual-ticket">
        <li>
          <label>Ticket Name</label>
          <input className="ticket-name" type="text" placeholder="E.g. General Admission" onChange={this.nameChange} />
        </li>
        <li>
          <label>Quantity Available</label>
          <input className="quantity" type="number" placeholder="100" onChange={this.quantityChange} />
        </li>
          <li>
            <label>Price</label>
            <input className="price" type="number" placeholder="25.00" onChange={this.priceChange} />
          </li>
        <li>
          <RemoveTicket clickHandler={this.props.deleteTicket} />
        </li>
      </ul>
    )
  }
});
```

Remove Ticket Button Component

```
var RemoveTicket = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return (
      <button type="button" className="delete-ticket" onClick={this.props.clickHandler}><i className="fa fa-trash-o delete-ticket"></i></button>
    );
  }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Updated - 13 Mar 2016**:

First I would store in the tickets array just the state of each ticket components and not the actual components. So the Tickets component would look like this:

```
var Tickets = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function() {
    return {
      tickets: [{name: 'someName', quantity: '20', price: 100}],
    }
  },
  createTicket: function() {
    var tickets = this.state.tickets
    tickets.push(
      {name: '', quantity: '', price: null}
    )
    this.setState(tickets);
  },
  nameChange: function(index, e) {
    let tickets = this.state.tickets;
    tickets[index] = merge(tickets[index], { name: e.target.value })
    this.setState({tickets: tickets});
  },
  quantityChange: function(index, e) {
    let tickets = this.state.tickets;
    tickets[index] = merge(tickets[index], {quantity: e.target.value })
    this.setState({tickets: tickets});
  },
  priceChange: function(index, e) {
    let tickets = this.state.tickets;
    tickets[index] = merge(tickets[index], {price: e.target.value })
    this.setState({tickets: tickets});
  },
  deleteTicket: function(index) {
    var tickets = this.state.tickets
    tickets.splice(index, 1); 
    this.setState({tickets: tickets});
  },
  render: function() {
    console.log("tickets:", this.state.tickets);

    return (
      <div>
        {this.state.tickets.map((ticket, index) =>
           <IndividualTicketInput key={index} {...ticket} 
             deleteTicket={this.deleteTicket.bind(null, index)}
             nameChange={this.nameChange.bind(null, index)}
             quantityChange={this.quantityChange.bind(null, index)}
             priceChange={this.priceChange.bind(null, index)}
             />
        )}
        <CreateTicket createTicket={this.createTicket} /><br/><br/>
      </div>
    );
  }
});
```

The spread attribute `{...ticket}` passes all the properties of ticket as properties for the `IndividualTicketInput` component.
`key={index}` is needed so the element gets an unique id.

I also pass the `deleteTicket` function which is also bound to the `index` parameter, so it knows which ticket to delete, using its index in the array. This is later passed to the `RemoveTicket` button as a onClick handler.

I moved the `nameChange`, `priceChange` and `quantityChange` functions to the `Tickets` component, so they have access to the `tickets` array and when any of these details change, they update it in the array rather than just in the local state of the `IndividualTicketComponent`. This way, the `Tickets` component has the latest state of all the children tickets.

`IndividualTicketInput` component doesn't store anything in its local state. It passes the values of the ticket to its input elements using the `value` attribute. When any of the value of these inputs changes, the handlers are called and the state is immediately updated in the corresponding array item.

```
var IndividualTicketInput = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function() {
    return { name: this.props.name, quantity: this.props.quantity, price: this.props.price };
  },
  render: function() {
    return (
      <ul className="individual-ticket">
        <li>
          <label>Ticket Name</label>
          <input className="ticket-name" type="text" placeholder="E.g. General Admission" onChange={this.props.nameChange} value={this.props.name} />
        </li>
        <li>
          <label>Quantity Available</label>
          <input className="quantity" type="text" placeholder="100" onChange={this.props.quantityChange} value={this.props.quantity} />
        </li>
        <li>
          <label>Price</label>
          <input className="price" type="text" placeholder="25.00" onChange={this.props.priceChange} value={this.props.price} />
        </li>
        <li>
          <RemoveTicket clickHandler={this.props.deleteTicket} />
        </li>
      </ul>
    )
  }
});
```

The `merge` function used in the handlers in the `Tickets` is part of the module `lodash`. For the sake of the exercise, I initialised the array with the state of a ticket with values different than empty or null, to see that it gets properly rendered and can be edited, also left a `console.log` in the render to see how the `tickets` array changes when you edit a ticket or add a new one.

In this setup, once you finished editing the tickets you can send the array in the `Tickets` component to your backend and save it in storage.

I created another [codepen](http://codepen.io/alexchiri/pen/dMpYep/) with it to see it in action.

Comment: Hi Alexandru, how would you go about passing the index of the ticket in the array to the lower component?

Comment: I owe you a coffee man after all the help you've given!! Do you have a paypal account?

Comment: @luke Ha ha, no need for that, it's my pleasure. I actually need to implement similar stuff for a project of mine and your question forced me to think a bit ahead :-) Let me know how it works for you and give my answer some green if it was good ;-)

Comment: I am getting these errors: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'bind' of undefined` and `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '_currentElement' of null` on the second click. I don't think `this.props.ticketIndex` gets passed through from the parent component or the spread attribute isn't passing the properties.

Comment: @luke the problem is that I wrote `this.props.deleteTicket.bind(this, this.props.ticketIndex)` in the RemoveTicket onClick handler. It should be `this.deleteTicket.bind(this, this.props.ticketIndex)` as the function is not part of the props.

Comment: and actually `this.deleteTicket.bind(this, this.props.ticketIndex)` gives a warning so better to use `this.deleteTicket.bind(null, this.props.ticketIndex)`. I did some other changes in the samples above, check the edit diffs and also the codepen.

Comment: Alexandru, seriously many thanks!! I think I am finally starting to get this whole react thing after a week of working with it. Love the fact that you can just create a component for something and use it anywhere, so awesome.

Comment: @luke yeah, it takes some time to get used to some of the react things. If my answer solves your problem, don't forget to accept the answer ;)

Comment: @luke when I started implementing this solution in my project I realised that is has some issues. I made another edit, so this time when you edit a ticket data, it gets updated in the tickets array and in the local state of the ticket component. Also if you initialise the array with an existing list of tickets, those values now get rendered rather than having empty values. I removed the `this.forceUpdate()` calls as they shouldn't be needed as long as you call the `this.setState` function and update the state.

Comment: Hi @alexandru, having a bit of issue. I'm loading loadash into the page but whenever I start typing in the name, quantity or price, I get the error in the console `merge is not a function`....any thoughts on what to do?

Comment: Nevermind. Application I was working with had underscore.js overriding loadash :)